# How to select percentage of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python I have a few dataframes structured like so:

```
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
. . . .
n n n n
```

**How can I select the middle 33% rows (determined by index, not value)?**

Here is what I attempted:

```
df.iloc[int(len(df)*0.33):int(len(df)*0.66)]
```

It does work but feels really messy, not to mention the forced ints.

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of selecting a percentage of a dataframe as I couldn't find any helpful commands in the documentation so far.

Comment: Every operation cant have a defined function in a library unless it is useful for most of the people. If you feel you dont like your own approach write a function.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use numpy percentile function on index. This method also works when your index doesn't start from zero.

```
df[(df.index>np.percentile(df.index, 33)) & (df.index<=np.percentile(df.index, 66))]
```

Comment: Not everything I was looking for but very useful in this context thank you. NaNPercentile documentation for anyone interested: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to do your task i.e

```
def get_middle(df,percent):

    start = int(len(df)*percent)
    end = len(df) - start

    return df.iloc[start:end]

get_middle(df,0.33)
```

Answer (score 1):

> split the data into 70:30  and try this

```
percentage=round(len(df)/100*70) 
documents(train) = df.head(percentage)  
test=df.iloc[percentage:len(df),:]
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to "play" with the numbers and define what are the indexes you want:

```
df.iloc[(len(df)// 3) : (len(df) - len(df)// 3), :]
```

or

```
df.iloc[(len(df)// 3) : (len(df)// 3 * 2), :]
```

in these examples I define an interval, namely `(len(df.index)// 3) : (len(df.index)// 3 * 2)`, that cuts the dataframe's rows comprised between 1/3 and 2/3 of the table.

Comment: accessing `.index`  is useless. You will get the same length if you use `df` directly

Answer (score -2):

If you're working on a real life data. And say you want to work on 0.01% (which is enough). Then use Pandas to do your work.

```
Dataframe.sample(frac=0.01)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Your solution picks random rows in the dataframe. The question asks how to select the middle third of all rows.